# Json data is not populated in treeview panel

Tags: json, extjs, treeview, extjs6-modern

here below is my json formate i need to show in the treeview panel in extjs6
After loading store from server i am not able to see any records in Tree panel.
what should be the Model view and store for this json rendering in to the Tree view panel .
Thanks.
here is my code :

Model :

```
 Ext.define('File', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
        fields: [
                    {number: 'number',     type: 'string'},
        ]
    });
```

Store :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: 'File',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'component-tree.json',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'components',

                leaf: true,
                children: 'components',
                expanded: true,

            },

        },

        folderSort: true,
    });
```

View :

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        autoLoad: true,
        collapsible: true,
        useArrows: true,
        rootVisible: true,
        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                appendOnly: true
            }
        },
        root: {
            text: "Components",
            expanded: true,

        },



        renderTo: document.body
    });
```

component-tree.json :

```
{
    "components": {
        "state": "RELEASED",
        "nodeType": "Component",
        "checked": true,
        "name": "PLATE - FOR CABINET - ASSEMBLY",
        "level": 0,
        "url": "http://example.com/Windchill/servlet/nexiles/tools/api/1.0/epmdocuments/OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474031",
        "oid": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474031",
        "modified": "17.04.2015",
        "filename": "21378386.asm",
        "num_children": 7,
        "number": "21378386.ASM",
        "details": "http://example.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474031&u8=1",
        "components": [
            {
                "nodeType": "Component",
                "leaf": true,
                "name": "PLATE - FOR CABINET - DETAIL",
                "level": 1,
                "url": "http://example.com/Windchill/servlet/nexiles/tools/api/1.0/epmdocuments/OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474018",
                "oid": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474018",
                "modified": "17.04.2011",
                "filename": "1234.prt",
                "state": "RELEASED",
                "number": "21378385.PRT",
                "details": "http://example.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474018&u8=1",
                "version": "A",
                "checked": true,
                "drawings": [
                    {
                        "reftype": "DRAWING",
                        "nodeType": "Drawing",
                        "leaf": true,
                        "name": "PLATE - FOR CABINET - DETAIL",
                        "url": "http://example.com/Windchill/servlet/nexiles/tools/api/1.0/epmdocuments/OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474013",
                        "oid": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474013",
                        "modified": "17.04.2015",
                        "filename": "21378385.drw",
                        "source": "representation",
                        "state": "RELEASED",
                        "number": "21378385.DRW",
                        "details": "http://example.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474013&u8=1",
                        "version": "A",
                        "checked": true,
                        "id": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474013-DRAWING",
                        "icon": "/resources/images/drawing.gif"
                    },
                    {
                        "reftype": "INTERNAL",
                        "nodeType": "Drawing",
                        "leaf": true,
                        "name": "PLATE - FOR CABINET - ASSEMBLY",
                        "url": "http://example.com/Windchill/servlet/nexiles/tools/api/1.0/epmdocuments/OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474041",
                        "oid": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474041",
                        "modified": "17.04.2015",
                        "filename": "21378386.drw",
                        "source": "representation",
                        "state": "RELEASED",
                        "number": "21378386.DRW",
                        "details": "http://example.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474041&u8=1",
                        "version": "A",
                        "checked": true,
                        "id": "OR:wt.epm.EPMDocument:4474041-INTERNAL",
                        "icon": "/resources/images/drawing.gif"
                    }
                ],
                "icon": "/resources/images/prt_image.gif"
            }
}
```

Comment: `leaf: true` in the reader configuration?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your treeModel just defines `number` but your store actually contains much more fields...
2. Take a look at [the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) in the chapter 'Heterogeneous node types' for more information.
3. Try with `children` instead of `components` in your json file. By the way I could remark that the case is not respected between the configuration `root: { text: "Components", ... }` and the json content `"components": [ ... ]`.
   `C` and `c`

Comment: Hello Michel . Actually thing is that i can not chage the json file . i tried i have get the solution but i am not able to render the "drawing" data in a tree . i mean sub child data is not showing only one level tree is showing . so how can i show the "drawing" data too in the tree ?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your test? I will try to modify it so that it works...